# Looping through custom post type in PHP/WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

very new to PHP - custom post type, which I'm retrieving and looping through the results to display on the screen. Is this the best way to do it?

Or is there a way to retrieve results from the meta data without having to do:

`get_the_ID(),'measure_description'`

...for every field in the meta/custom post?

Also, `$postauthor = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'post_author',true);` shows blank - how can I retrieve the post author from the query/results I have?

```
$query_args = array( 
        'post_type'             => 'tftracker',
    //  'author'                => '1',
    //  'author_name'           => 'Mark',
        'order'                 => 'ASC',
        'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'              => 'result_date',
        'nopaging'              => true,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'unit_type',
                'value'     => 'steps',
                'compare'   => '=',
       )
    )
);

// Run the query.
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  $measure = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'measure_description',true);
  $record = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'unit_type',true);
  $latestres = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'latest_result',true);
  $datet = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'result_date',true);
  $postauthor =get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'post_author',true);
    
echo('<ul>');
echo('<li><strong>post_author:</strong> ' . $postauthor . '</li>');
echo('<li><strong>Measure:</strong> ' . $measure . '</li>');
echo('<li><strong>Record:</strong> ' . $record . '</li>');
echo('<li><strong>Result:</strong> ' . $latestres . '</li>');
echo('<li><strong>Date:</strong> ' . $datet . '</li>');
echo('</ul>');
    }
} else {
    // Display a no posts found message here.
}

// Reset post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You don't need to supply the `key` for every `get_post_meta`. Just do something like `$post_meta = get_post_meta( $id )`. That will give you all post meta for that post. You'll still have to do something like `$post_meta[0]['measure_description']`. Also, in my example, assign `$id = get_the_ID();` - for the author, WP has a built in function called `get_the_author()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/

Comment: Thank you - I ended up with this:

 $post_meta = get_post_meta( $id );
  $measure = $post_meta['measure_description'][0];
  $record = $post_meta['unit_type'][0];
  $latestres = $post_meta['latest_result'][0];
  $datet = $post_meta['result_date'][0];
  $postauthor = get_the_author();

Thanks for your help